# Juego de la granja - El cerdo ha desaparecido ¿Por qué no se ve?

Tags: javascript

Es el juego de la granja. Consigo ver el fondo, las vacas y los pollos pero no el cerdo. Veo que al activar el Switch devuelve error en la linea del switch y ya no se ven el fondo ni las vacas. No consigo depurar el error. ¿Qué sucede? ¿Dónde están el cerdo y los pollos?

**Error (el depurador marca esta linea):

[image: Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined** (Señala la linea del switch)]

Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Javascript:**

```
var pp = document.getElementById ("jueguito");
var lienzo = pp.getContext("2d");

var xVaca= new Array();
var yVaca= new Array();

var xCerdo= 150;
var yCerdo= 100;

var xPollo= new Array();
var yPollo= new Array();


function moverCerdo(e){
    var movimiento= 64;
    var teclas= {
        LEFT: 37,
        RIGHT: 39,
        UP: 38,
        DOWN: 40
    };

    switch(e.keyCode)
    {
        case teclas.LEFT: 
            xCerdo= xCerdo - movimiento;
            dibujar(xCerdo, yCerdo);
            break; 

        case teclas.UP:
            yCerdo= yCerdo - movimiento;
            dibujar(xCerdo, yCerdo);
            break;

        case teclas.RIGHT:
            xCerdo= xCerdo + movimiento;
            dibujar(xCerdo, yCerdo);
            break;

        case teclas.DOWN:
            yCerdo= yCerdo + movimiento;
            dibujar(xCerdo, yCerdo);
            break;

    }

    
}







var fondo= {
    URL: "tile.png",
    cargaOk: false
};

var vaca = {
    URL: "vaca.png",
    cargaOk: false
};

var pollo = {
    URL: "pollo.png",
    cargaOk: false
};

var cerdo = {   
    URL: "cerdo.png",   
    cargaOk: false   
};

fondo.imagen = new Image();
fondo.imagen.src= fondo.URL;
fondo.imagen.addEventListener("load", cargarFondo);

pollo.imagen= new Image();
pollo.imagen.src= pollo.URL;
pollo.imagen.addEventListener("load", cargarPollo);

cerdo.imagen = new Image();
cerdo.imagen.src= cerdo.URL;
cerdo.imagen.addEventListener("load", cargarCerdo);

vaca.imagen= new Image();
vaca.imagen.src= vaca.URL;
vaca.imagen.addEventListener("load", cargarVaca);


function cargarFondo()
{
    fondo.cargaOk= true;
    dibujar();
}

function cargarVaca()
{
    vaca.cargaOk= true;
    mantenerPosicion();
}

function cargarPollo()
{
    pollo.cargaOk= true;
    mantenerPosicion();
}

function cargarCerdo()
{
    cerdo.cargaOk= true;
    dibujar();
}




function mantenerPosicion()
{
    if(vaca.cargaOk)
    {
        var cantidad = aleatorio(1, 5);
        for(var i=0; i<cantidad; i++)
        {
            var x = aleatorio(0, 6);
            var y = aleatorio(0, 6);
            x = x*70;
            y = y*70;
            xVaca[i] = x;
            yVaca[i] = y; 
        }
    }

    if(pollo.cargaOk)
    {
        var cantidad = aleatorio(1, 5);
        for(var i=0; i<cantidad; i++)
        {
            var x = aleatorio(0, 6);
            var y = aleatorio(0, 6);
            x = x*70;
            y = y*70;
            xPollo[i] = x;
            yPollo[i] = y; 
        }
    }
    dibujar();
}




function dibujar()
{
    if (fondo.cargaOk== true)
        {
        lienzo.drawImage(fondo.imagen, 0, 0);
        }

    if (vaca.cargaOk== true)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            lienzo.drawImage(vaca.imagen, xVaca[i], yVaca[i]);  
        }
    }

    if (pollo.cargaOk== true)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            lienzo.drawImage(pollo.imagen, xPollo[i], yPollo[i]);       
        }
    }


    if (cerdo.cargaOk== true)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            lienzo.drawImage(cerdo.imagen, xCerdo[i], yCerdo[i]);       
        }
    }
}




function aleatorio(max, min)
{
    var numero_aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return numero_aleatorio;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Primer proyecto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Mueve al cerdo</h1>
    <p>Mueve al cerdo hasta la granja para ganar</p>
    <canvas width="500" height="500" id="jueguito"></canvas>
    <script src="juego.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Y hay varias imágenes que comparto:**

Fondo:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dDfeqs-Hf8DrbFqCzVCFLmrGTRRjS3Cm/view?usp=sharing
Cerdo:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xktx8LcICVVZ8YwR7AEPguzbPv9oVnUO/view?usp=sharing
Pollo:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18jCrm2h1E4JKO2qSwzqmAiNCY7GjFdxr/view?usp=sharing
Vaca:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rdbRIaHxfZeM1tmb013pKety19TWhe37/view?usp=sharing

Comment: No estoy seguro del problema, pero tu función `dibujar` no toma ningún argumento, sin embargo en el `switch` para mover el cerdo le pasas 2. Además de eso, dentro de dibujar, usas `xCerdo` y `yCerdo` como si fueran arreglos, pero inicialmente los declaras como números...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El siguiente código JS me funcionó. La posición del cerdo aquí es un array, pero si vas a tener solo uno, puede ser un número...lo importante es que si es que a la hora de tratarlo en las funciones lo uses de la misma forma.
La función `moverCerdo` en tu código se declara pero nunca la usabas:

```
var pp = document.getElementById ("jueguito");
var lienzo = pp.getContext("2d");

var xVaca= new Array();
var yVaca= new Array();

var xCerdo= [150];
var yCerdo= [100];

var xPollo= new Array();
var yPollo= new Array();


function moverCerdo(e){
    switch(e.key)
    {
        case 'a': 
            xCerdo[0] -= movimiento;
            dibujar();
            break; 

        case 'w':
            yCerdo[0] -= movimiento;
            dibujar();
            break;

        case 'd':
            xCerdo[0] += movimiento;
            dibujar();
            break;

        case 's':
            yCerdo[0] += movimiento;
            dibujar();
            break;

    }

    
}


var fondo= {
    URL: "tile.png",
    cargaOk: false
};

var vaca = {
    URL: "vaca.png",
    cargaOk: false
};

var pollo = {
    URL: "pollo.png",
    cargaOk: false
};

var cerdo = {   
    URL: "cerdo.png",   
    cargaOk: false   
};

fondo.imagen = new Image();
fondo.imagen.src= fondo.URL;
fondo.imagen.addEventListener("load", cargarFondo);

pollo.imagen= new Image();
pollo.imagen.src= pollo.URL;
pollo.imagen.addEventListener("load", cargarPollo);

cerdo.imagen = new Image();
cerdo.imagen.src= cerdo.URL;
cerdo.imagen.addEventListener("load", cargarCerdo);

vaca.imagen= new Image();
vaca.imagen.src= vaca.URL;
vaca.imagen.addEventListener("load", cargarVaca);


function cargarFondo()
{
    fondo.cargaOk= true;
    dibujar();
}

function cargarVaca()
{
    vaca.cargaOk= true;
    mantenerPosicion();
}

function cargarPollo()
{
    pollo.cargaOk= true;
    mantenerPosicion();
}

function cargarCerdo()
{
    cerdo.cargaOk= true;
    dibujar();
}




function mantenerPosicion()
{
    if(vaca.cargaOk)
    {
        var cantidad = aleatorio(1, 5);
        for(var i=0; i<cantidad; i++)
        {
            var x = aleatorio(0, 6);
            var y = aleatorio(0, 6);
            x = x*70;
            y = y*70;
            xVaca[i] = x;
            yVaca[i] = y; 
        }
    }

    if(pollo.cargaOk)
    {
        var cantidad = aleatorio(1, 5);
        for(var i=0; i<cantidad; i++)
        {
            var x = aleatorio(0, 6);
            var y = aleatorio(0, 6);
            x = x*70;
            y = y*70;
            xPollo[i] = x;
            yPollo[i] = y; 
        }
    }
    dibujar();
}




function dibujar()
{
    if (fondo.cargaOk== true)
        {
        lienzo.drawImage(fondo.imagen, 0, 0);
        }

    if (vaca.cargaOk== true)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            lienzo.drawImage(vaca.imagen, xVaca[i], yVaca[i]);  
        }
    }

    if (pollo.cargaOk== true)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            lienzo.drawImage(pollo.imagen, xPollo[i], yPollo[i]);       
        }
    }


    if (cerdo.cargaOk== true)
    {
        lienzo.drawImage(cerdo.imagen, xCerdo[0], yCerdo[0]);       
    }
}




function aleatorio(max, min)
{
    var numero_aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    return numero_aleatorio;
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
    moverCerdo(e)
})
```